# A pattern for All Changed Files scope in Intellij IDEA

Tags: intellij-idea

Prior to changes introduced in IDEA 2020.1 or so, there was a convenient scope in Project overview. The scope was called *All Changed Files* and it contained a view of a VCS *Default Changelist*.

[image]

After recent changes the scope was removed. *Default Changelist* it accessible through `Alt + 9`, but it's not as convenient as it had been.

[image]

My question is, how to recreate *All Changed Files* scope using a pattern? I have tried to fetch it from a previous version of IDEA, but it's not listed in *Scopes* menu, so it is impossible copy the expression.

Comment: Could you please try to File | Invalidate Cache and Restart? Would it help? Also could you please clarify whether you have faced such behavior right after an upgrade or after IDE restart?

Comment: I can confirm, things back to previous state right after the restart. I remember it was an update a day or two before I observed the issue, however, I can not guarantee I faced the problem right after it. Thank you for the hint!